# Angular Permission Guard issue

Tags: angular, ngxs

The issue is everytime I refresh the page, sometimes the **permissions$** Obeservable is returning a blank array and sometimes not. What do you think is wrong with my code?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  @Select(UserState.permissions) permissions$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.permissions$.pipe(map(permissions => {
      for (const perm of next.data.permissions) {
        if (permissions.includes(perm)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: HI. How do you init a store? Do you wait for store init before navigation?

Comment: I init a store in app.component.ts, where should I put it to make it run before the navigation?

Comment: You can use APP_INITIALIZER for init the store before navigation. Doc: https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER
More details: https://indepth.dev/hooking-into-the-angular-bootstrap-process/

Answer (score 0):

I use a filter in my rxjs stream and wait until some condition. This is not tested, so please don't copy and paste.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  @Select(UserState.permissions) permissions$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.permissions$.pipe(
      // the idea here is if the permissions exists and is an array, then we can continue
      filter(permissions => !!permissions && Array.isArray(permissions)),
      map(permissions => {
        for (const perm of next.data.permissions) {
          if (permissions.includes(perm)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }));
  }
}
```